# Добавить в dataframe колонку из другого по условию

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Есть 2 файла excel. Первый:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Второй:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Желаемый результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь объединить:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('Номенклатура.xlsx', sheet_name='Лист3')
df2 = pd.read_excel('Номенклатура.xlsx', sheet_name='Лист4')

a = df1.merge(df2[['Номенклатура наименование полное']])

a.to_excel(r'Номенклатура1.xlsx', index=False)
```

Подскажите, как можно достичь объединения таблиц?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
a = df1.merge(df2, on='Номенклатура наименование полное')
```

Но потом ещё придётся с названиями колонок поработать, к ним припишутся суффиксы (по умолчанию `_x` и `_y`).

Если нужны только определённые колонки датафреймов - укажите их:

```
a = df1[['Колонка1','Колонка2','Номенклатура наименование полное']].merge(df2[['Колонка3','Колонка4','Номенклатура наименование полное']], on='Номенклатура наименование полное')
```

Если нужно, чтобы в результат попали строки с пустыми колонками - измените тип объединения через параметр `how=` который по умолчанию выставляется в `inner`. Например, можно поменять на `outer` и тогда в результат попадут и строки, которым не находится соответствия в одной из таблиц:

```
.merge(..., how='outer')
```

[Документация](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), где можно посмотреть все параметры.

Comment: благодарю за ответ! Суффиксы меня пугают здесь меньше всего) Если этот код использовать, то теряются данные с пустыми ячейками (ЦенаЗакуп, ЦенаИнтернет)

Comment: @Ireen1985 вы приведите в вопросе хотя бы часть воспроизводимых исходных данных. лучше не в xls, конечно.

Comment: @CrazyElf, я поняла, что меня устроит и такой вариант! Благодарю ещё раз!

Comment: @Ireen1985 Я дополнил ответ )

Comment: @CrazyElf, да-да, вижу. Спасибо, всё работает!